# Partial order and total order definitions

Tags: order-theory

i was wondering if anyone could give me a clear a few definitions;  of a partial order and a total order, and also a lattice. Any source which could aid in my understanding would be appreciated.

Comment: One question per post please! Edit this post to contain just one of your questions, and post your other questions in a new post.

Comment: (among other things, one of the problems of having multiple questions in one post is that it discourages people who might want to answer one question but not all of them)

Comment: Wikipedia and other web sites have those definitions.  Do three web searches and ignore the complainers.